# How can I refresh a fragment after deleting an item of a recycler view

Tags: android, android-fragments

the problem is this:
I have a Fragment that contains a recycler view of cards that are generated dynamically with information that come from FireBase, each card has a delete button attached to itself, the thing that I want to do is just refresh the fragment when I click the delete button inside of the card in order to show the remaining cards. The problem is that the button is inside of my adapter called AdapterServices and i don't know how to access to the fragment to perform the atach or detach operations over it. Sorry for this silly question i'm new on Android development and i'm really stucked with this.
Here is the code of AdapterServices:

```
package com.store.adapters;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.store.R;
import com.store.Servicios;
import com.store.famous.FragmentDeleteService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;

public class AdapterServices extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterServices.ViewHolderService> {
    private ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> itemPrices = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> itemDescriptions = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> itemMaximumTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private String stringContext;

    public AdapterServices(ArrayList<String> itemNames, ArrayList<String> itemPrices, ArrayList<String> itemDescriptions, ArrayList<String> itemMaximumTimes, Context context, String CONTEXT) {
        this.itemNames = itemNames;
        this.itemPrices = itemPrices;
        this.itemDescriptions = itemDescriptions;
        this.itemMaximumTimes = itemMaximumTimes;
        this.context = context;
        this.stringContext = CONTEXT;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderService onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int id = 0;
        boolean hasCardOnClickAtached = false;
        boolean hasCardDeleteButton = false;
        if (stringContext.equals("view")) {
            id = R.layout.view_services_item;
        } else if(stringContext.equals("modal")){
            id = R.layout.service_item;
            hasCardOnClickAtached = true;
        } else {
            id = R.layout.delete_services_item;
            hasCardDeleteButton = true;
        }
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(id, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderService(view, hasCardOnClickAtached, hasCardDeleteButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolderService holder, int position) {
        holder.serviceName.setText(itemNames.get(position));
        final String serviceName = holder.serviceName.getText().toString();
        holder.servicePrice.setText("$"+itemPrices.get(position));
        final String servicePrice = holder.servicePrice.getText().toString();
        holder.serviceDescription.setText(itemDescriptions.get(position));
        final String des = holder.serviceDescription.getText().toString();
        holder.serviceMaximumTime.setText(itemMaximumTimes.get(position) + " horas");
        final String maxTime = holder.serviceMaximumTime.getText().toString();
        if (holder.card != null) {
            holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Servicios.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("name", serviceName);
                    intent.putExtra("price", servicePrice);
                    intent.putExtra("description", des);
                    intent.putExtra("maximum_hours", maxTime);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else if(holder.btnDeleteService !=null){
            holder.btnDeleteService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final View view = v;
                    new SweetAlertDialog(v.getContext(), SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("¿Realmente deseas eliminar este servicio?")
                            .setContentText("Esta acción no se puede revertir")
                            .setConfirmText("Sí")
                            .setCancelText("No")
                            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {

                                }
                            })
                            .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {

                                }
                            })
                            .show();

                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemNames.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderService extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView serviceImage;
        TextView serviceName;
        TextView servicePrice;
        TextView serviceDescription;
        TextView serviceMaximumTime;
        @Nullable CardView card;
        @Nullable Button btnDeleteService;
        @Nullable Button btnUpdateService;
        FrameLayout fl;

        public ViewHolderService(@NonNull View itemView, boolean hasCardOnClickAtached, boolean hasCardDeleteButton) {
            super(itemView);
            serviceImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            serviceName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            servicePrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
            serviceDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
            serviceMaximumTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_maximum_time);
            card = null;
            btnDeleteService = null;
            btnUpdateService = null;
            if (hasCardOnClickAtached) {
                card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_card);
            } else if(hasCardDeleteButton) {
                btnDeleteService = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteService);
                fl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fl_del_ser);
            }
//            else {
//                // btnUpdateService = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteService);
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry I forgot to put more information. Here is my code in the fragment called FragmentDeleteService

```
package com.store.famous;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.store.R;
import com.store.SharedPreferencesApp;
import com.store.adapters.AdapterServices;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link FragmentDeleteService#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentDeleteService extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private SharedPreferencesApp preferencesApp;
    private String artistUserName;

    public FragmentDeleteService() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentDeleteService.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentDeleteService newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentDeleteService fragment = new FragmentDeleteService();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_delete_service, container, false);
        fillData(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void fillData(View v){
        final View view = v;
        final ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> itemPrices = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> itemDescriptions = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> itemMaximumTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
        final String CONTEXT = "delete";
        preferencesApp = new SharedPreferencesApp(getContext());
        preferencesApp.loadPreferences();
        artistUserName = preferencesApp.getArtistUsername();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("data").child(artistUserName).child("servicios");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot element : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    itemNames.add(element.child("nombre").getValue().toString());
                    itemPrices.add(element.child("precio").getValue().toString());
                    itemDescriptions.add(element.child("detalles").getValue().toString());
                    itemMaximumTimes.add(element.child("tiempoMaximo").getValue().toString());
                    itemIds.add(element.getKey());
                }
                recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_delete_services);
                recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                AdapterServices adapter = new AdapterServices(itemNames, itemPrices, itemDescriptions, itemMaximumTimes, itemIds, getContext(), CONTEXT);
                recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the updated code of the oncilick listener of my btnDeleteServices that belongs to my adapter called AdapterServices, i decided to include the method that deletes the card from RecyclerView, but as I said, the recycler duplicates the remaining items, I'm very confused

```
else if(holder.btnDeleteService !=null){
            holder.btnDeleteService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final View view = v;
                    new SweetAlertDialog(v.getContext(), SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("¿Realmente deseas eliminar este servicio?")
                            .setContentText("Esta acción no se puede revertir")
                            .setCancelText("No")
                            .setConfirmText("Sí")
                            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                                    sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                                    String id = itemIds.get(pos);
                                    SharedPreferencesApp preferencesApp = new SharedPreferencesApp(context);
                                    preferencesApp.loadPreferences();
                                    String username = preferencesApp.getArtistUsername();
                                    itemNames.remove(pos);
                                    itemDescriptions.remove(pos);
                                    itemPrices.remove(pos);
                                    itemMaximumTimes.remove(pos);
                                    itemIds.remove(pos);
                                    DatabaseReference df = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                            .getReference("data")
                                            .child(username)
                                            .child("servicios")
                                            .child(id);
                                    df.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Eliminación satisfactoria", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: notifyDatasetChanged(); add this line after you delete the item and that will be updated into the Recycler view

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer CodeRED Innovations, actually i have done this and works, but something weird happens, when the element is deleted, the recycler duplicates the remaining items

Comment: Please add code for the `Fragment` where you have added this `RecyclerView`.